# Issue running python script in separate folder

Tags: python, sys

I Have a directory structured as follows:

```
application
 ├── app
 │   └── folder
 │       └── file_1.py 
 │       └── Model_data
 │            └──data.csv
 └── app2
     └── some_folder
         └── file_2.py
```

I want to import a function from file_1 inside of file_2.  I use:

```
from application.app.folder.file_1 import load_data

t = load_data()
```

the problem is that this returns an error.  Within the function load_data I call pandas and import csv data from a sub-folder.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Model_data/data.csv')
```

this returns a "file doesn't exist error".
how do I resolve this?

file_1 runs fine from within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing `'Model_data/data.csv'` to its absolute path. example `C:/application/app/folder/Model_data/data.csv`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I'm actually doing this as part of a testing routine and the file_1.py script gets exported to an aws lambda function, so changing the directory isn't an ideal option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path from `file_1.py`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def load_data():
   file_1_path = Path(__file__)
   filename = file_1_path.parent / "Model_data" / "data.csv"
   df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```